# Fill in cells in specific columns if cells are blank

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I am looking to edit this function I saw in a older post to something that is more dynamic and can actually fill in the blanks on the right column since right now it is filling in Column B instead of the blanks in D. Here is the function I have

```
function Absent() {
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var values = tss.getRange("Attendance!D1:D20").getValues();

  for(i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    var value = values[i][0];

    if (value == "") {
      var rangeB = tss.getSheetByName("Attendance").getRange(i+1,2);

      if(!rangeB.isBlank()) {
        rangeB.setValue("A");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]
The current situation I have is that there are names in Column A that are marked with a P (because they are present) in columns "D","H","J","L","N","P","R","T","V","X","Z","AB","AF","AH","AJ","AL","AN" The people who are not there are left blank but I would like to fill them in with A when I run the scrip through a button. Here you can see the [sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZBrg4XoeL21mXwn93XT35kgjrE5pqx9cd3xEvfojIXM/edit?usp=sharing) 
The script below is what I run first to add Ps to everyone that is present but I am not sure how to edit to where after it adds P's it goes back in and if name is not found put an A so that is why I am doing the second script. But if there is a way to just add it to this one that would be great!

```
  var sprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var transpose = sprsheet.getSheetByName("Transpose");
  var attendance = sprsheet.getSheetByName("Attendance");

  //Ranges of Transpose
  var colDates = transpose.getRange("D1:BU1").getValues();
  var attendees = transpose.getRange("D2:BU2").getValues();

  //Ranges of Attendance
  var eventsCol = ["D","H","J","L","N","P","T","V","X","Z","AB","AF","AH","AJ","AL","AN","AR","AT","AV","AX","AZ","BD","BF","BH","BJ","BL","BP","BR","BT","BV","BX","BZ"]; //Add Column letters is need more dates added 
  var kids = attendance.getRange("A2:A205").getValues(); //Increase this if you add more names 

  loop1:
  for (var i = 0; i < eventsCol.length; i++){ //For each column 

    var list = getIndividuals(attendees[0][i]); //Get the list of each Transpose row 2

    loop2:
    for (var x = 0; x < kids.length; x++){ //For each name in Attendance

      loop3:
      for (var y = 0; y < list.length; y++){ //Compare it with each name of the list

        if (list[y] == kids[x][0] || list[y] == " " + kids[x][0]){ //Second "or" is in case there is an space in the first position.

        attendance.getRange(eventsCol[i]+(x+2)).setValue("P");

          break loop3; //Once it finds a name it makes no sense to keep searching. Go back to the next name.

         }         
        } 

      }

    }
  }


//Split the list into each name, removing the first space
function getIndividuals(attendees){

  var individuals = attendees.split(",");

  for (var i = 0; i < individuals.length; i++){ 

    if (individuals[i][0] == " "){

      individuals[i][0].replace(" ", "");

    }

  }

  return individuals;
}
```

Comment: I'd be glad to help.  Can I see an image of your sheet?

Comment: @Cooper I just uploaded an image of it. It is also linked on the post. Thank you so much!

Comment: These columns `"D","H","J","L","N","P","R","T","V","X","Z","AB","AF","AH","AJ","AL","AN"` don't seem to agree with your image.

Comment: Do you have a copy of your current attendance script?

Comment: @Cooper I don't I know how to  post my script as a comment here so I just added it to my post. Also I am pretty sure the columns you named do match up since thats where I am populating my Ps into. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Filling in the Empties With an A**

Hmm. Great school.  You get an A even if you don't show up.

```
function fillTheEmptiesWithA() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cols= ["D","H","J","L","N","P","R","T","V","X","Z","AB","AF","AH","AJ","AL","AN"];
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Attendance');
  var sr=3;
  cols.forEach(function(c,i){
    var col=sh.getRange(c+1).getColumn();
    var rg=sh.getRange(sr,col,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,1)
    var vals=rg.getValues();
    vals.forEach(function(p,j,v){if(p==''){v[j][0]='A';}});
    rg.setValues(vals);
  });
}
```

According to this `var kids = attendance.getRange("A2:A205").getValues();` your data starts on row 2.  According to you image your data starts on row 3.  I put a startRow(sr) into the code so that you could decide which one it is later.

Animation:

[image]

*This version only fills Empties when header row is not blank in each column

```
function runTwo() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cols= ["D","H","J","L","N","P","R","T","V","X","Z","AB","AF","AH","AJ","AL","AN"];
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Attendance');
  var sr=3;
  cols.forEach(function(c,i){
    var col=sh.getRange(c+1).getColumn();
    if(sh.getRange(sr-1,col).getValue()!='') {
      var rg=sh.getRange(sr,col,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,1)
      var vals=rg.getValues();
      vals.forEach(function(p,j,v){if(p==''){v[j][0]='A';}});
      rg.setValues(vals);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: First off great catch ! I didn't see that I did have it starting at 2 but 3 is actually correct. Secondly, great joke lol (A= absent ). Lastly, thank you so much this works like a charm I am tremendously grateful I was stuck for hours trying to figure it out. Thank you again @Cooper

Comment: Hi @Rihco! Please, accept @cooper ´s answer if it worked for you so that we know that is the right solution.

Comment: @Cooper would it be possible to add a statement that says something like  fill in only when  Column header has text? The thing is that we run daily reports not semester reports so ideally we would run this script daily.

Comment: @MateoRandwolf I am asking for an edit but I will accept it one Its totally done, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Yeah The column header request is an easy one. I gather that your saying that some of those columns don’t have dates yet. I’ll get that done in about an hour.

Comment: Yes exactly the headers of  ```"D","H","J","L","N","P","R","T","V","X","Z","AB","AF","AH","AJ","AL","AN``` will not have dates until data is inputted. THANKS! Sorry I didnt mention it earlier

Comment: @Cooper any luck with getting the script to look at headers first?

Comment: Yes.  It's on the bottom of my answer.

Comment: fantastic! Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

your current script does the following:
1) Retrieve D1:10
2) check through the values of D1:D10 to see which is empty
3) if the range is empty, set a value of A on the 2nd column.

the following script would:
1) check through the given range
2) check for empty value
3) set a value of A on the same range

```
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var checkrange = sheet.getRange(2,1,9,1).getValues(); //range to check getRange(starting row, starting column,number of rows to check, number of column to check)

  for( i=0; i<checkrange.length; i++){ 
    var content = checkrange[i];

    if (content ==""){
      sheet.getRange(i+2,1).setValue("A"); //plus 1 because first item in array is a 0, but it would be in row 1, plus another 1 because of header. to change the column, change the 1 to whichever column you need
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I cant seem to make it work. For some reason when I run the script nothing happens. Could you check if I have something wrong.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZBrg4XoeL21mXwn93XT35kgjrE5pqx9cd3xEvfojIXM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Also I think this might want to put an A in every cell that is empty disregarding what column its in. I would like it to only check the range of specific columns